# C++ Skipping the Login Dialog Box

Tags: c++, mfc

We are using an C++ Application that has been provided by the company we do work for. We don't code in c++, we use python and js etc. We don't have the knowledge in c++ to skip the dialog login box. Reason for the skip we need to open the exe file without having to click the "OK" button to continue to the main app after the login.

Here's the DlgLgin.cpp file, I assume we can skip the dialog from this script.

```
// DlgLogin.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "clientdemo.h"
#include "DlgLogin.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CDlgLogin dialog

#define WM_MSG_LOGIN        WM_USER + 0x1000
#define WM_MSG_LOAD         WM_USER + 0x1001


CDlgLogin::CDlgLogin(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CDlgLogin::IDD, pParent)
{
    //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CDlgLogin)
//#ifdef _DEBUG
#define USER 5

#if (USER == 5)
    m_strUser = _T("admin");
    m_strPsw = _T("password");
    m_strIP = _T("ip_address");
#endif

// #else
//  m_strUser = _T("USER_NAME");
//  m_strIP = _T("OUR_IP");
// #endif
    m_usSvrPort = 6605;
    m_bLogining = TRUE;
    
    //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
}


void CDlgLogin::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CDlgLogin)
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_IP, m_strIP);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_PSW, m_strPsw);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_USER, m_strUser);
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDlgLogin, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CDlgLogin)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_MSG_LOGIN, OnMsgLogin)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_MSG_LOAD, OnMsgLoad)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CDlgLogin message handlers

void CDlgLogin::OnOK() 
{
    // TODO: Add extra validation here
    
    CWaitCursor wait;
    // SendMessage(IDOK, BM_CLICK, 0);
    if (!m_bLogining)
    {
        if (!UpdateData())
        {
            return ;
        }
        
        m_strUser.TrimLeft();
        m_strUser.TrimRight();
        m_strIP.TrimLeft();
        m_strIP.TrimRight();
        if (m_strUser.IsEmpty() || m_strIP.IsEmpty())
        {
            AfxMessageBox(_T("Name or Server ip is empty."));
            return ;
        }
                
        NETCLIENT_RegLoginMsg(this, FUNLoginMsgCB);
        int nEr  = NETCLIENT_LoginDirSvr(CStringA(m_strIP), m_usSvrPort, "", 
            CStringA(m_strUser), CStringA(m_strPsw), 1);
        

//      m_strIP.ReleaseBuffer();
//      m_strUser.ReleaseBuffer();
//      m_strPsw.ReleaseBuffer();
//      NETCLIENT_SetUserSvrInfo(m_strIP.GetBuffer(0), m_usSvrPort);
//      PostMessage(WM_MSG_LOGIN, GPS_LOGIN_SUC, 0);
        theApp.SetLoginInfo(m_strIP, m_usSvrPort, _T(""), m_strUser, m_strPsw);
        m_bLogining = true;
        EnableCtrl(TRUE);
        m_bLoginSuc = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        NETCLIENT_RegLoginMsg(NULL, NULL);
        NETCLIENT_LogoutDirSvr();
        if (m_bLoginSuc)
        {
            m_loadThread.StopDeviceLoad();
            m_bLoginSuc = TRUE;
        }
        m_bLogining = false;
        EnableCtrl(TRUE);
        
    }

    // CDialog::OnOK();
}

void CDlgLogin::OnCancel() 
{
    // TODO: Add extra cleanup here
    
    CDialog::OnCancel();
}

BOOL CDlgLogin::OnInitDialog() 
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    
    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    char szBuf[10] = {0};
    int n = szBuf[9]-szBuf[0];
    
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}

void CDlgLogin::EnableCtrl(BOOL bEnable)
{
    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_USER)->EnableWindow(bEnable);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_PSW)->EnableWindow(bEnable);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_IP)->EnableWindow(bEnable);
    GetDlgItem(IDOK)->EnableWindow(bEnable);
    GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL)->EnableWindow(bEnable);
}

void CDlgLogin::FUNLoginMsgCB(int nMsg, void * pUsr)
{
    CDlgLogin* pThis = (CDlgLogin*)pUsr;
    pThis->DoLoginMsgCB(nMsg);
}

void CDlgLogin::DoLoginMsgCB(int nMsg)
{
    PostMessage(WM_MSG_LOGIN, nMsg);
}

LRESULT CDlgLogin::OnMsgLogin(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(wParam)
    {
    case GPS_LOGIN_SUC:
        //      SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_CNT_SUC));
    //  theApp.SetSvrIP(m_strIP, GetSvrPort());
        CSvrVer::GetInstance()->SetSvrVer(NETCLIENT_GetSvrVersion());
        m_bLoginSuc = TRUE;
        //m_loadThread.SetLoadMsg(GetSafeHwnd(), WM_MSG_LOAD);
        m_loadThread.StartDeviceLoad(TRUE);
        break;
    case GPS_LOGIN_FAILED:
        //  SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_CNT_ERR));
        //  m_stInfo.SetWindowText(LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_CNT_ERR));
        //      UpdateText();
//      OnLoginFailed(LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_CNT_ERR));
        break;
    case GPS_LOGIN_DISCNT:
        //SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_USR_ERR));
        //  UpdateText();
        break;
    case GPS_LOGIN_NAME_ERR:
        //      SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_USR_ERR));
        //      UpdateText();
    //  m_cmbUser.SetFocus();
    //  OnLoginFailed(LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_USR_ERR));
        break;
    case GPS_LOGIN_PWD_ERR:
        //      SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_PWD_ERR));
        //      UpdateText();
    //  OnLoginFailed(LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_PWD_ERR));
        break;
    case GPS_LOGIN_FULL_ERR:
        //      SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_FULL_ERR));
        //      UpdateText();
    //  OnLoginFailed(LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_FULL_ERR));
        break;
    case GPS_LOGIN_VER_ERR:
        //      SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_VER_ERR));
        //      UpdateText();
    //  DoVersionError();
        break;
        //  case GPS_LOGIN_EXIST:
        //      SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_EXIST));
        //      UpdateText();
        //      OnLoginFailed();
        //      break;
    case GPS_LOGIN_USR_DEL:
        //      SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_USER_DEL));
        //      UpdateText();
    //  OnLoginFailed(LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_USER_DEL));
        break;
    case GPS_LOGIN_EXPIRED:
        //      SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_USER_EXPIRED));
        //      UpdateText();
    //  OnLoginFailed(LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_USER_EXPIRED));
        break;
    case GPS_LOGIN_SERVER_EMPTY:
        //      SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_EXPIRED_TIP_FULL_EMPTY_ERR));
        //      UpdateText();
    //  OnLoginFailed(LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_EXPIRED_TIP_FULL_EMPTY_ERR));
        break;
    default:    
        //      SetDlgItemText(IDC_ST_INFO, LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_CNT_ERR));
        //      UpdateText();
    //  OnLoginFailed(LOADSTRINGEX(ID_STR_DLG_LOGIN_TIP_CNT_ERR));
        break;
    }

    if (wParam != GPS_LOGIN_SUC)
    {

        CString str;
        str.Format(_T("login fail error %d"), wParam);
        AfxMessageBox(str);
        EnableCtrl(TRUE);
    }
    
    UpdateData(FALSE);
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CDlgLogin::OnMsgLoad(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (!m_bLogining)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    switch(wParam)
    {
    case LOAD_ING:
        break;
    case LOAD_FAILED:
        AfxMessageBox(_T("load fail"));
        EnableCtrl(TRUE);
        break;
    case LOAD_FINISHED:
        NETCLIENT_RegLoginMsg(NULL, NULL);
        CDialog::OnOK();
        break;
    case LOAD_CONFIG_SUC:
        PostMessage(WM_MSG_LOAD, LOAD_FINISHED);
        break;
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Login Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyHLt.png)

We hard coded the login information in the DlgLogin.cpp.

If I can provide more information please let me know.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Ehm if you're going to have a hardcoded password (I soo not recommending that) why show a dialog box at all? Just run the login code and exit the application

Comment: We are trying to skip the dialog box, we don't need it. The executable file we run after building the solution file forces the dialog box. Reason for the hard coded information, it sits behind a firewall and private network.

Comment: You can call OnCancel() function in OnInitDialog(). As this way, When Initialize the LoginDialog, close Dialog automatically. Alternatively, you can prevent Dialog from being modaled in App.cpp.

Comment: @Edwar I was looking in my memory (it's a long long time since I did MFC). I was thinking of simulating the button click by posting a button click message or enter key press. But that would do it to :)

Comment: @Edwar Thank you for the advice. the OnCancel() function, where is best practice to add this in the code? Sorry I haven't worked with MFC before.

Comment: @duvankre8 Post as an answer to show the code.

Comment: @PKramer could you assist with the code to simulate a button click? The OnCancel() call is not working for me. Would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy.
You can change code like this.

```
BOOL CDlgLogin::OnInitDialog() 
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    
    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    char szBuf[10] = {0};
    int n = szBuf[9]-szBuf[0];
    
    OnCancel();
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

Otherwise you can remove this part in the app.cpp

```
CDlgLogin dlgLogin; 
if (IDOK != dlgLogin.DoModal()) 
{ 
    return FALSE; 
}
```

Comment: This caused the exe file to not launch. I can try the other method of just not calling the DlgLogin(), I can provide the source code to the equivalent of the app.cpp file.

Comment: CDlgLogin dlgLogin;

 if (IDOK != dlgLogin.DoModal())
 {
  return FALSE;
 }


 CClientdemoDlg dlg;
 m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
 int nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
 if (nResponse == IDOK)
 {
  // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
  //  dismissed with OK
 }
 else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
 {
  // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
  //  dismissed with Cancel
 }

Comment: that to me looks like where it gets called in our main.cpp.

Comment: You can remove modal part in app.cpp.  please remove this.    CDlgLogin dlgLogin; if (IDOK != dlgLogin.DoModal()) { return FALSE; }

Comment: @duvankre8 don't put code in comments, as you can see it's unreadable. Instead [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69162094/edit) and put that code _there_.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code a bit longer  I decided to follow the
user message pattern. It is already used in the code.

```
// Part where user messages are defined, we add an extra one.
#define WM_MSG_LOGIN        WM_USER + 0x1000
#define WM_MSG_LOAD         WM_USER + 0x1001
#define WM_MSG_OK           WM_USER + 0x1003 // <== Add this

// At this place in the code we tell the dialog to call
// OnMsgOk (we can't call OnOk directly since signatures of functions don't match)
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDlgLogin, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CDlgLogin)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_MSG_LOGIN, OnMsgLogin)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_MSG_LOAD, OnMsgLoad)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_MSK_OK, OnMsgOk)              // <== Add this
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// Add this handler, near ::OnMsgLogin 
LRESULT CDlgLogin::OnMsgOk(WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/)
{
    OnOk();    // call the code that's normally called when OK button is pressed
    return 0;
}

// At end of OnInitDialog post the message 
// this call will return immediately (unlike ::SendMessage)
// so dialog can finsh OnInitDialog (in base classes) completely
// before handling calling OnMsgOk.
::PostMessage(WM_MSG_OK, 0, 0);
```

I hope this works or is close enough to get closer to a solution.

Comment: I'd rather not use `WM_USER + X` but `WM_APP + X`.

Comment: Using `WM_USER` messages in a window class you did not register (like a dialog) is a sure recipe for disaster.